# Declare and Initialize a const Struct in Class Header

Tags: c++, struct, header, constants, declare

I am looking for way to Declare and Initialize a constant struct in my Class Header file.
The class is being used by an MFC app, as you can see.
The layers on my MFC Dialog will never change, so I would like to delcare them constantly.

I am looking for something like this:

```
class CLayerDialog : CDialogEx
{
...
public:
   const LAYER_AREA(CPoint(0, 70), CPoint(280, 140));
}
```

The struct:

```
struct LAYER_AREA{
   CPoint topLeft;
   CPoint bottomRight;
};
```

What is the best way to do this, to save as much performance as possible and to easily maintain the layers?

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: So you want the LAYER_AREA to be const in each object or you want it to be the same single object available in all the objects of CLayerDialog?

Comment: I want it to be the same single object of CLayerDialog. Which always stays the same, yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a `static const` member variable?

```
// header file
class CLayerDialog : CDialogEx
{
/* ... */
public:
   static const LAYER_AREA myvar;
};

// source file
const LAYER_AREA CLayerDialog::myvar(CPoint(0, 70), CPoint(280, 140));
```

Note that the variable *must be defined out-of-line* (in the source file rather than the header file).  You'll also need an appropriate constructor for `struct LAYER_AREA` as well.

Comment: This was true in C++03, and probably still the best approach for Visual C++, although the next version ought to have better support for *brace-or-equal-initializer* syntax.

Comment: Alright, so there I will have to use the CPP file for that?

Comment: @Future: Yup, the CPP "source file".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this: ( I have made a few assumptions about the classes you had not provided )

**in header file**

```
class CDialogEx
{
   public:
      CDialogEx (){}
};

class CPoint
{
   public:
      CPoint ( const int& _x, const int& _y ):x(_x), y(_y){}

   private:
      int x;
      int y;

};

struct LAYER_AREA
{
   CPoint topLeft;
   CPoint bottomRight;
   LAYER_AREA ( CPoint tl, CPoint br ):
      topLeft ( tl ), bottomRight ( br )
   {
   }
};

class CLayerDialog : CDialogEx
{
   public:
      CLayerDialog ();
      const LAYER_AREA myStructVar;
};
```

**in .cpp file**

```
CLayerDialog::CLayerDialog()
  : myStructVar ( CPoint(0, 70), CPoint(280, 140) )
{

}
```